# DDD - What is the best way to Query complex relationships (To do a Select on repository or to use AutoMapper)?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Imagine that I have an object with many relationships and I want to return just one property of each relationship in a list.

```
public class MyComplexObject
{
  public OtherObject1 OtherObject1 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject2 OtherObject2 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject3 OtherObject3 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject4 OtherObject4 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject5 OtherObject5 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject7 OtherObject7 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject8 OtherObject8 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject9 OtherObject9 { get; set; }
  public OtherObject10 OtherObject10 { get; set; }
}
Public class MyComplexObjectDto 
{
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject1 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject2 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject3 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject4 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject5 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject6 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject7 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject8 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject9 { get; set; }
  public string PropertyOfOtherObject10 { get; set; }
}
```

1º aproach:
I query the entire relationship of the MyComplexObject and to use the AutoMapper to serialize just the data I want.

```
public class MySercice: IApplicationService
{
  private readonly IRespoitory _myComplexObjectRepository;
  public MySercice(IRespoitory myComplexObjectRepository)
  {
    _myComplexObjectRepository = myComplexObjectRepository;
  }
    public async Task<List<MyComplexObjectDto>> GetMyComplexObject()
    {
      var objList = _myComplexObjectRepository.GetListAsync()
      return ObjectMapper.Map<List<MyComplexObject>, List<MyComplexObjectDto>>(obj);
    }
}
```

2º aproach:
I make a Linq.Select query getting just the data I want from the repository.

```
public class MyComplexObjectRepository: IRespository
{
  private Context MyContext;
  public MyComplexObjectRepository(Context myContext)
  {
    MyContext = myContext;
  }

  public Task<List<MyComplexObjectDto>> GetSerializedObjectList()
  {
    return myContext.MyComplexObject.Select( data => new MyComplexObjectDto {
      PropertyOfOtherObject1  = data.OdetherObject1.FirstOrDefault( some complex value).value,
      PropertyOfOtherObject2 = data.OdetherObject2.AnotherRelationship.AnthotherValue,
      PropertyOfOtherObject3 = data.OdetherObject3.Sum( another complex value).ToString(),
      PropertyOfOtherObject4 = data.OdetherObject4.someOtherValue,
      PropertyOfOtherObject5 = data.OdetherObject5.AnotherObject.Value,
      PropertyOfOtherObject6 = data.OdetherObject6,                 
      PropertyOfOtherObject7 = data.OdetherObject7,
      PropertyOfOtherObject8 = data.OdetherObject8,       // This query can get very complex //
      PropertyOfOtherObject9 = data.OdetherObject9,
      PropertyOfOtherObject10 = data.OdetherObject10
    });
  }
}
```

Thinking about DDD and Performace,
I'm trying to find out what is the best choice as the Aplication.Contracts Layer should never see The Domain layer
And The Repository should not see The Aplication.Contracts .

Should I return All related data (it can be a very huge relation chain) and serialize this hole list of objects in the aplication layer?

Should I Make the MyComplexObjectDto as a view model and store it in the domain layer? if yes how do I refenrece the the IApplicationService? should I crate another dto and "duplicate" this class in the Application.Contracts?

I hope I could express What is the problem I'm dealing with

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all the data of the complex object from the database and transfer all the data to the DTO and return. I can't recommend this, you can create a method in ApplicationService for each use-case and return information according to the needs of the use-case.
2. Get all the data of the complex object from the database and transfer the relevant data to the DTO and return. This is generally a good method, but you should be very careful about the size of the data you pull from the database. For example, consider the ABP Docs module:

As you know, the ABP Docs module allows you to read documents, so the content of the document is kept in the database and updated periodically. Anyway, content can be huge, and calling it on every DB query will cause performance issues. There is no need for content, especially in the part where we show the documents as a list, for this we created the following class in the Domain layer:

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/docs/src/Volo.Docs.Domain/Volo/Docs/Documents/DocumentWithoutContent.cs

If there is no need for content in a use-case, we return this object with select while pulling data from the Database. https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/3fa526c4a124baa27f314c0c02af5949a1ce9245/modules/docs/src/Volo.Docs.EntityFrameworkCore/Volo/Docs/Documents/EFCoreDocumentRepository.cs#L203-L216

---

You should not put your DTO objects in the domain or infrastructure layer. For more information, you can read the book "Implementing Domain-Driven Design" =>

https://abp.io/books/implementing-domain-driven-design